# Getting Error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when creating string literal - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

While running my code I get the error 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' in a number of places and I don't know why. It seems like a string literal should not be ambiguous.

I'm running Xcode 11 GM and I do get it to work when I cast it to a String but then I get an error when setting the color for the Text. This is not solved by casting it to a color.

`let currentRed: Double = Double.random(in: 0..<1)

```
var body: some View {

    return Text(String("Red \(Int(currentRed * 255.0))")) // <- Returns Error without cast to String
               .foregroundColor(Color(red: self.currentRed, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0)) // <- Returns same error }
```

I expect to be able to set the foregroundColor but I keep on getting this error. Is this a bug?

Comment: With SwiftUI the error is not always where the compiler indicates. The error may be up or down the code several hundreds of lines. The code you posted is correct, so the problem is somewhere else. You'll need to post more. A good troubleshooting technique is start commenting code, until the error goes away. When it does, you probably reached the guilty line.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. I kept on thinking it was with that line and I couldn't figure out why. Is this just a bug or is this intended? I doubt it's intended. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug, but also probably not intended. It seems they still have some work to do.;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no errors when I use this syntax:

```
Text("Red \(currentRed * 255.0)")
    .foregroundColor(Color(red: self.currentRed, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0))
```

And here's the output:

[image]

You're using at least three type conversions - `String`, `Int`, and whatever you call `\()` where it appears you just want the last one.

If you wish to display the integer value, just change your line to:

```
Text("Red " + String(Int(currentRed * 255.0)))
    .foregroundColor(Color(red: self.currentRed, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0))
```

Sample output:

[image]

(Keep in mind, since you are adding a random number, the output isn't identical!)

Comment: Thank you! You made me realize I forgot to cast it to an Int! I still have the problem with the error but according to kontiki's comment (to the actual question to this thread) it's caused by some other line.